# SQL : Data retrieval is slow for large number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

DBMS :  Microsoft SQL Server 
**UPDATED** -- Total Number of Records in table : 972848614
**UPDATED** -- Query Returning Rectors

**UPDATED**
Query to get Count : select count(*) from MemberBetDetail where memberCode='test' and betstatusId = 1 and winlossAmount != 0

**It took 9:46 minutes and the RESULT : 4741350**

Query to get result: select memberCode,betstatusId,winlossAmount   from MemberBetDetail where memberCode='test' and betstatusId = 1 and winlossAmount != 0

**It took 7:26 minutes and the RESULT :4741350**

Table Schema and Indexes

[image: Table Schema]

[image: Indexes]

There are total 4753780 records that I want to retrieve but it took almost 8 minutes. Can someone point out what is the actual problem with it

I am using simple query based on MemberCode, CurrencyCode and StatusId

**Updated :**

Execution Plan[image]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Show us the query you are using and the execution plan.

Comment: This might not be an answer but a tip, have you consider using index to speed up the query?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?" or "why my query is slow ") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: DBMS : SQL. Query : select * from table  where membercode='test' and currencyCode='RM' and statusId in (1,2)

Comment: Query is very slow. it took almost 8 to 9 minutes

Comment: please check this link to know more on how to improve your question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: "SQL" is **not** a "DBMS". It's a query language that is used by _every_ relational DBMS. But looking at the screenshots that looks like Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: How many rows has this table? If you fetch 1/100 or less of it's volume, it can be ok use this index, if you fetch almost all the table full scan will be faster

Comment: Around 8 or 9 million records. Every 6 months we just archive data

Comment: From your picture it seems to me that estimated number of rows is very small, the arrows are too thin, can you tell us how many rows are expected? (pass your mouse over select in the plan)

Comment: So you try to fetch all the table ( a half of the table is the same in this sense), full scan will be faster

Comment: You can force the scan using hint with(index =0), but you should update statistics because the estimate is not correct

Comment: Is the DB local / on the same network or in another location? If it is remote, sending back 4mn records over a WAN will be slow. Alos, it's worth questioning why you want 4mn records - is that number really useful? Do you want some other aggregate of them?

Comment: I have updated info

Answer (score 0):

try by setting nonclustered index for the table ...

```
create NONCLUSTERED  index myIndex on Table1(Column2) include (col1,col2,clo3)
```

Comment: First :

[MemberCode] ASC,
[BetStatusID] ASC

Second :

[ProviderCode] ASC,
[BetID] ASC

Third :

[UpdatedDate] ASC,
[BetStatusID] ASC

Comment: pls refer this site http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Tricks-to-increase-SQL-Server-query-performance

Comment: try to use column names instead of select *

Comment: select * from table (nolock) where membercode='test' and currencyCode='RM' and statusId in (1,2) try using nolock

Comment: how much records do u have in the ouput ?

Comment: Index can magically reduce the data retrieval time but have a reverse effect on DML operations, which may degrade query performance.    try by removing index

Comment: refer this site http://www.developer.com/db/slideshows/10-ways-to-improve-sql-query-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

As Nithin said, try replacing * in your query by columns you need and include these columns in a new index based on the 3 columns used in the WHERE clause.
This shoud avoid the need of key lookup.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX OPTIM_1 ON MemberBetDetail(MemberCode ASC, CurrencyCode ASC, BetStatusId ASC) 
       INCLUDE (colYouNeed1, colYouNeed2, ColYouNeed3)
```